# ejabberd server mod_archive module

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I am trying to set up Message archiving for my ejabberd server.  I tried to add new module mod_archive following the link http://lboynton.com/2009/11/25/ejabberd-mod_archive-with-mysql-on-ubuntu/. After that i am not able to restart ejabberd  server and gives me the following error in ejabberd.log

=ERROR REPORT==== 2010-11-16 12:44:41 ===
E(<0.38.0>:ejabberd_rdbms:67) : Start of supervisor ejabberd_odbc_sup_localhost failed:
{error,{shutdown,{child,undefined,ejabberd_odbc_sup_localhost,
{ejabberd_odbc_sup,start_link,["localhost"]},
transient,infinity,supervisor,
[ejabberd_odbc_sup]}}}

Thanks,

Sathi.

Answer (score 6):

All internet tutorials about mod_archive in Ejabberd are incomplete or very caotics. Or maybe are old. So my problem is I am using Ubuntu 12.04 server LTS with Mysql. And I did all the things that are explained in all blogs.

So to install mod_archive I need to do this:

The typical:

```
svn co https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules
cd ejabberd-modules/mod_archive/trunk
./build.sh
cp ebin/*modules in EJABBERD
```

and configure `/etc/ejabberd.cfg`

but with this methods EJABBERD does not work.

So I discover that we need to compile other MODULE that are not explained in any site. The module is called CONN_MYSQL

And we can get in the same ejabber-modules dowloaded. So in SVN (https://svn.process-one.net/ejabberd-modules) there are

```
cd ejabberd-modules/mysql/trunk
./build.sh
cp ebin/*modules in EJABBERD
```

And work.....

I need a lot of hours to discover this.

I can not use this line configuration in ejabberd.cfg: `{odbc_server, "DSN=ejabberd;UID=ejabberd;PWD=ejabberd"}` because aplication crashes and says this:

```
=ERROR REPORT==== 2012-11-28 18:01:08 ===
E(<0.437.0>:mod_archive_odbc:867) : should_store_jid failed: {xmlelement,
                                                              "error",
                                                              [{"code","500"},
                                                               {"type",
                                                                "wait"}],
                                                              [{xmlelement,
                                                                "internal-server-error",
                                                                [{"xmlns",
                                                                  "urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas"}],
                                                                []}]}
```

So I use this line in ejabberd.cfg:
    {odbc_server, {mysql, "server", "database", "username", "password"}}.

and this line into the modules configuration:

```
  {mod_archive_odbc, [{database_type, "mysql"}, {default_auto_save, true}, {enforce_default_auto_save, true}]},
```

So now works!

I don't remmember if i use

`trunk` or `branches/ejabberd-2.0.x` in Emakefile . You could try one and if not works you could try the other.

Ah! and remmember to compile with

```
./configure --enable-odbc the ejabberd source code.
```

You can get this in

```
wget http://www.process-one.net/en/ejabberd/ejabberd/2.1.11/ejabberd-2.1.11.tgz
```

maybe it is necessary this packages:

```
apt-get install iodbc libmyodbc
```

Comment: Hi if i run ./bulid.sh getting error: ~/ejabberd-modules/mod_archive/trunk$ ./build.sh
{"init terminating in do_boot",{undef,[{make,all,[]},{init,start_it,1},{init,start_em,1}]}}.Please help

Crash dump was written to: erl_crash.dump
init terminating in do_boot ()

Comment: @JamesVo You missed the erlang-tools debian package.

Answer (score 0):

I used this one without any errors: http://www.ndl.kiev.ua/content/mod_archive_odbc-release